# Codeigniter date validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check validation of my date in codeigniter. The date format will be yyyy-mm-dd. If someone type other way. I want to show error message. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter doesnt include date validation. You should validate manual like that:

```
$yourdate = '2015-03-09';
$pattern = '/^(19|20)\d\d[\-\/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[\-\/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/';

if (!preg_match($pattern, $yourdate)) 
{
    echo 'Your date does not match the YYYY-MM-DD format.';
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Your date is correct!';      
}
```

**Demo:** https://eval.in/297663